# Django-rest-resetpassword not submitting new password into the database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement password reset using Django-rest-resetpassword package.

```
urls.py
path('account/password-reset/', include('django_rest_resetpassword.urls', namespace='password_reset')),

views.py
@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def password_reset_token_created(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):

    # send an e-mail to the user
    context = {
        'current_user': reset_password_token.user,
        'user_name': reset_password_token.user.user_name,
        'email': reset_password_token.user.email,
        'reset_password_url': "{}?token={}".format(
            instance.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('password_reset:reset-password-confirm')),
            reset_password_token.key),
        'site_name': "crispy"
        
    }
    # render email text
    email_html_message = render_to_string('account/user/reset_password.html', context)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        # title:
        "Password Reset for {title}".format(title="Account API"),
        # message:
        email_html_message,
        # from:
        "noreply@example.com",
        # to:
        [reset_password_token.user.email]
    )
    msg.attach_alternative(email_html_message, "text/html")
    msg.send()

Templates
User/rest_password.html
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}Hello from {{ site_name }}!
You're receiving this e-mail because you requested to change your password.
It can be safely ignored if you did not request a password reset. Click the link below to reset your password.
{{ reset_password_url }}
{% if user_name %}{% blocktranslate %}In case you forgot, your username is {{ user_name }}.{% endblocktranslate %}
{% endif %}Thank you for using {{ site_name }}!
{{ site_domain }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

I followed the procedure in the website
https://pypi.org/project/django-rest-passwordreset/
I'm able to send password reset message to the user email and the user recieves token. But the problem I'm having is that when I enter the token for the password confirmation the program tells me that it's successful but I'm not able to login with the new password. when I check the password reset table in the database nothing appears.The new password isn't entering Into the database. Am I missing any critical step?

Comment: Passwords are (normally) never entered in their plain form in the database, but *hashed*.

Comment: Can you add the part of your code which updates the password into the database?

Comment: @Dean Elliott Yeah I can. please check the code, I've updated it.

Comment: Sorry, not the view which sends the token but the view which updates the user password following the `password_reset:reset-password-confirm` link.

Comment: @ Dean Elliott Oh, I see. I didn't do that and I don't understand how to implement that update code with Django-rest-resetpassword. I thought the package takes care of the update process at the core by default. Please enlighten me on that.  The code I have above is what I have in my program.